# get warning "componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed" after moving expo project to react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I migrate my expo project to react native project.
I removed expo and i tried to use the native way to add splash screen and push notifications and to add fonts without expo. 
I also installed react navigation with the native way without expo.
I run the project using android studio and Xcode. 
I have some problems but i fixed them by fixing some packages versions in my package.json file
Now i get this error :

```
Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. See ... for details.

* Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
* If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static getDerivedStateFromProps. Learn more at: ***
* Rename componentWillReceiveProps to UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project source folder.

Please update the following components: SafeView
```

my old packeges file :

```
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk- 
     33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
     ....
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.3",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^1.0.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",

My current version use safe area context with react navigation :

    "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.7.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.0.6",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "buffer": "^5.4.3",
    "color": "^3.1.2",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.7.26",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.5",
    "native-base-autocomplete": "^1.3.2",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-event-source": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.6",
    "react-native-globalize": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-modal-selector": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.16.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-responsive-ui": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.3",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^1.0.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "search-params": "^2.1.3",
    "whatwg-url": "^8.0.0"
  },
```

Comment: so is there any problem or error? try replacing componentWillReceiveProps to componentDidUpdate

Comment: I got a warning . the problem that i don't use componentWillReceiveProps in any of my components

Comment: From which library SafeView is being imported ? It seems to be the one using componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: its not in your component, it maybe inside any react native packages

Comment: i really don't know but i think it's a problem with the navigation that use react-native-safe-area-context

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case actually this is not an error. This is a warning from react native.

**componentWillReceiveProps** is a synchronous hook. Calling asynchronous function like data fetching inside this hook will need to render in between when the new props are set and when data has finished loading.

Thus, **componentWillReceiveProps** is being deprecated in favor of the following reason:

1. Use **componentDidUpdate**

So, I suggest you to use componentDidUpdate hook as far as possible and update your code.

- The similar things happen when comparing **componentWillMount** and **componentDidMount**. Use **componentDidMount** whenever you need operate async operation and forget **componentWillMount** at all condition.

Comment: i never used componentWillReceiveProps in my app

Comment: @KhaledBoussoffara Ok .. Check your third party dependencies. I think one of them have this hook inside. That's why you got a warning

Comment: how can i find the third party that used this function ?

Comment: @KhaledBoussoffara using debugging you can exactly identify the library. But do not change the library code by yourself.Instead of doing that go to github of the specific library and check they have migrated to new hooks. If not make PR or add issue :)

Comment: Nice ! If these informations are worth then don't forget to upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

You should find the package from which SafeView object used.
-import SafeView from "......."-

Then you can find this package folder from node_modules folder.
Then you should search the code and find "componentWillReceiveProps".
Rename this to UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps as declared in the warning.

It worked on the same problem with my app. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I fixes this warning by reinstalling the navigation and the dependencies that used, so my current packages files is :

```
 "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.7.1",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
"@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.0.6",
"axios": "^0.19.0",
"buffer": "^5.4.3",
"color": "^3.1.2",
"libphonenumber-js": "^1.7.26",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"native-base": "^2.13.5",
"native-base-autocomplete": "^1.3.2",
"querystring": "^0.2.0",
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-event-source": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.6",
"react-native-globalize": "^3.0.0",
"react-native-material-textfield": "^0.16.1",
"react-native-modal-selector": "^1.1.1",
"react-native-paper": "^3.6.0",
"react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.9",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
"react-native-responsive-ui": "^2.1.1",
"react-native-root-toast": "^3.1.2",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
"react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
"react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
"react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
"react-navigation": "^4.1.1",
"react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.4",
"react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.1.5",
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.1.1",
"react-redux": "^7.1.0",
"redux": "^4.0.4",
"redux-devtools": "^3.5.0",
"redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
"search-params": "^2.1.3",
"whatwg-url": "^8.0.0"
```

thanks to everyone